# How to describe the interface of chained arrow functions?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is pretty simple case if i want to descripbe it as standalone function

```
interface IProps {
    name: string
}
const renderer = ():React.FC<IProps> => ({name}:IProps) => <div>{name}</div>
```

I want to use this kind of function inside a class

```
interface zzz {
  renderer: ???
}
class ZZZ {
  renderer = ():React.FC<IProps> => ({name}:IProps) => <div>{name}</div>
}
```

I've got no idea how to describe the interface

Comment: How about `renderer = () => React.FC<IProps>`  ?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about how to declare functions in interface, then you need to do it like this:

```
interface zzz {
   renderer(): React.FC<IProps>
}
```

Furthermore, if you want to use that specific function in a class and define it, you need to implement the interface.

```
class ZZZ implements zzz {
   rerender(): React.FC<IProps> {
     return (
          ({name: IProps}) => <div>{name}</div>
      );
   }
```

As far as chaining arrow functions go, it only means that you are returning another function, so the above syntax holds well for your use-case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I wanted to define interface, something like this:
interface zzz {
  renderer: () => () => React.Node
}
Is it possible?